# How to align laser beams?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, experimental-physics, laser

This question is of experimental concern. Let's say I have two counterpropagating laser beams, each coming out of a fiber coupler. In the path of the beams, I have two mirrors and, say, an atomic vapour cell.
My question is: how can I make the two laser beams overlap exactly during their respective path, each one going from one fiber coupler to the other? The only thing I can manipulate is the position of the objects and the mirrors' orientations. I can also use a powermeter.

It seems every researcher does this every day but I cannot find a methodic way to do this!

Comment: *"It seems **every** researcher does this on a day to day basis"* - wow!

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is put an adjustable aperture in the two beams.  then move it around they system.  When the beams are aligned you will see nothing on either side of the aperture throughout the entire system.  Just the glow around the aperture.  With fiber couplers, adjust beam A until it couples into coupler B and vice versa.  This won't happen until the beams are collinear.